# is the "were" in the following sentence past simple tense or subjunctive mood

Tags: conditional-constructions, subjunctives

I encountered this sentence while wasting my time on twitter.

> Literally no one would believe warm words about McCain from Trump were sincere so he’s better off not even making a pretense.

Assuming the above sentence is grammatically correct, I am puzzled by the use "were" and quite frankly is having a hard parsing the whole sentence structure. Is the "were" used here a subjunctive mood of "be", or is it used as the past tense of "be"?

The first half of the sentence seems to me a shortened version of "

> If Trump said something warm..., no one would believe it is (were?)
>   sincere.

i.e. second conditional/present and future unreal events. So I guess my real question is do we use subjunctive mood in the dependent clause of a consequence clause?

Comment: What is the source?

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide the original link to the tweet as this is just some random stuff I jotted down while browsing. I honestly don't even remember the author but he/she is definitely a native speaker so I assume it is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say the intention of the author, but I would say simple past as written:

> Literally no one would believe...
>   (that) warm words about McCain from Trump **were** sincere...
>   so he’s better off not even making a pretense.

To make it subjunctive:

> Literally no one would believe...
>   (that) warm words about McCain from Trump **would be** sincere...
>   so he’s better off not even making a pretense.

Comment: Which one makes more sense? I don't understand the sentence structure of the original, assuming it is correct. It seems to be a general observation of hypothetical  general situation, rather than conterfactual situation from past. I fail to see the reason behind the use of past tense be.

Answer (score 0):

In your comparison using the singular it would be 'was', not 'were':

> If Trump said something warm, no one would believe it **was** sincere. (not 'were')

Therefore it looks like this pattern does not trigger the irrealis subjunctive 'were'.

Actually the irrealis subjunctive 'were' in English [has very limited use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_past_subjunctive), pretty much just cases that follow the patterns 'if it were', 'suppose it were', or 'I wish it were'.

The original sentence is fine.  A paraphrase could be:

> If Trump offered warm words about McCain, literally no one would believe it was sincere.  Therefore, it's better for Trump to not even make a pretense.